# Why is the rbindlist() function causing fatal errors in RStudio when working with bigger data, even if I have memory for it?

Tags: r, memory, data.table

I'm doing a project with my professor and I have to combine large datafiles together into one big datafile to manipulate. I'm trying to combine a 336 MB file with a 42 MB file by loading them in (read_csv()), putting both in a list (list()), and then using rbindlist() to combine them together. According to the Memory Usage Report, only 14% of my memory is in use, so why does it crash when I try to combine them? It was working fine with earlier files (I've been combining them recursively), which had less data, but it doesn't seem like I'm running short on memory.

I've tried removing the datafiles and calling gc() before using rbindlist (though I obviously keep the list that needs to be binded). I've tried looking at similar questions on this site but I can't really find anything.

```
contracts201415 <- read_csv("Data/contracts201415.csv")
contracts2015Q3 <- read_csv("Data/Csv/contracts_Q3_2015.csv")

bindlist <- list(contracts201415, contracts2015Q3)
contracts <- rbindlist(bindlist, fill=T)
write.csv(contracts, "/Data/contracts.csv")
```

The code is breaking on the rbindlist line. For the first datafile, the columns are:

```
  .. cols(
  ..   ...1 = col_double(),
  ..   ...2 = col_double(),
  ..   contract_unique_id = col_character(),
  ..   seller_company_name = col_character(),
  ..   customer_company_name = col_character(),
  ..   contract_affiliate = col_character(),
  ..   ferc_tariff_reference = col_character(),
  ..   contract_service_agreement_id = col_character(),
  ..   contract_execution_date = col_character(),
  ..   commencement_date_of_contract_term = col_character(),
  ..   contract_termination_date = col_character(),
  ..   actual_termination_date = col_character(),
  ..   extension_provision_description = col_character(),
  ..   class_name = col_character(),
  ..   term_name = col_character(),
  ..   increment_name = col_character(),
  ..   increment_peaking_name = col_character(),
  ..   product_type_name = col_character(),
  ..   product_name = col_character(),
  ..   quantity = col_character(),
  ..   units = col_character(),
  ..   rate = col_character(),
  ..   rate_minimum = col_character(),
  ..   rate_maximum = col_character(),
  ..   rate_description = col_character(),
  ..   rate_units = col_character(),
  ..   point_of_receipt_balancing_authority = col_character(),
  ..   point_of_receipt_specific_location = col_character(),
  ..   point_of_delivery_balancing_authority = col_character(),
  ..   point_of_delivery_specific_location = col_character(),
  ..   begin_date = col_character(),
  ..   end_date = col_character(),
  ..   ...33 = col_double().
```

The second file is the same in the same order, without the weird col_double() columns (which I believe appeared from an earlier rbindlist function). However, it hasn't been a problem in those earlier bindings. I figured I could fix it after I combined the data but if it's the problem, I try to fix it now.

Here is the str() output for both files. The first:

```
tibble [973,155 Ã 30] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ contract_unique_id                   : chr [1:973155] "C7" "C8" "contract_unique_id" "C6" ...
 $ seller_company_name                  : chr [1:973155] "3C Solar LLC" "3C Solar LLC" "seller_company_name" "Abest Power & Gas, LLC" ...
 $ customer_company_name                : chr [1:973155] "Portland General Electric Company" "Portland General Electric Company" "customer_company_name" "ISO New England Inc" ...
 $ contract_affiliate                   : chr [1:973155] "N" "N" "contract_affiliate" "N" ...
 $ ferc_tariff_reference                : chr [1:973155] "3C Solar, LLC, MBR Tariff, 0.1.0" "3C Solar, LLC, MBR Tariff, 0.1.0" "ferc_tariff_reference" "FERC Electric Tariff, 0.0.0" ...
 $ contract_service_agreement_id        : chr [1:973155] "Lever" "Ilg" "contract_service_agreement_id" "ISO-NE MPSA" ...
 $ contract_execution_date              : chr [1:973155] "20110630" "20130502" "contract_execution_date" "20130201" ...
 $ commencement_date_of_contract_term   : chr [1:973155] "20110630" "20130502" "commencement_date_of_contract_term" "20130427" ...
 $ contract_termination_date            : chr [1:973155] "20260630" "20280502" "contract_termination_date" NA ...
 $ actual_termination_date              : chr [1:973155] NA NA "actual_termination_date" NA ...
 $ extension_provision_description      : chr [1:973155] "None" "None" "extension_provision_description" "None" ...
 $ class_name                           : chr [1:973155] "UP" "UP" "class_name" "N/A" ...
 $ term_name                            : chr [1:973155] "LT" "LT" "term_name" "N/A" ...
 $ increment_name                       : chr [1:973155] "Y" "Y" "increment_name" "N/A" ...
 $ increment_peaking_name               : chr [1:973155] "FP" "FP" "increment_peaking_name" "N/A" ...
 $ product_type_name                    : chr [1:973155] "MB" "MB" "product_type_name" "MB" ...
 $ product_name                         : chr [1:973155] "ENERGY" "ENERGY" "product_name" "ENERGY" ...
 $ quantity                             : chr [1:973155] "498.96" "387" "quantity" NA ...
 $ units                                : chr [1:973155] "KW" "KW" "units" NA ...
 $ rate                                 : chr [1:973155] "0.3988" "0.2099" "rate" NA ...
 $ rate_minimum                         : chr [1:973155] NA NA "rate_minimum" NA ...
 $ rate_maximum                         : chr [1:973155] NA NA "rate_maximum" NA ...
 $ rate_description                     : chr [1:973155] NA NA "rate_description" "Market Based" ...
 $ rate_units                           : chr [1:973155] "$/KWH" "$/KWH" "rate_units" "$/MWH" ...
 $ point_of_receipt_balancing_authority : chr [1:973155] NA NA "point_of_receipt_balancing_authority" NA ...
 $ point_of_receipt_specific_location   : chr [1:973155] NA NA "point_of_receipt_specific_location" NA ...
 $ point_of_delivery_balancing_authority: chr [1:973155] "PGE" "PGE" "point_of_delivery_balancing_authority" NA ...
 $ point_of_delivery_specific_location  : chr [1:973155] "Interconnection of 3C Solar facility and PGE" "Interconnection of Newman facility and PGE" "point_of_delivery_specific_location" NA ...
 $ begin_date                           : chr [1:973155] NA NA "begin_date" NA ...
 $ end_date                             : chr [1:973155] NA NA "end_date" NA ...
```

The second:

```
spc_tbl_ [156,939 Ã 31] (S3: spec_tbl_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ contract_unique_id                   : chr [1:156939] "C7" "C8" "contract_unique_id" "C6" ...
 $ seller_company_name                  : chr [1:156939] "3C Solar LLC" "3C Solar LLC" "seller_company_name" "Abest Power & Gas, LLC" ...
 $ seller_history_name                  : chr [1:156939] NA NA "seller_history_name" NA ...
 $ customer_company_name                : chr [1:156939] "Portland General Electric Company" "Portland General Electric Company" "customer_company_name" "ISO New England Inc" ...
 $ contract_affiliate                   : chr [1:156939] "N" "N" "contract_affiliate" "N" ...
 $ ferc_tariff_reference                : chr [1:156939] "3C Solar, LLC, MBR Tariff, 0.1.0" "3C Solar, LLC, MBR Tariff, 0.1.0" "ferc_tariff_reference" "FERC Electric Tariff, 0.0.0" ...
 $ contract_service_agreement_id        : chr [1:156939] "Lever" "Ilg" "contract_service_agreement_id" "ISO-NE MPSA" ...
 $ contract_execution_date              : chr [1:156939] "20110630" "20130502" "contract_execution_date" "20130201" ...
 $ commencement_date_of_contract_term   : chr [1:156939] "20110630" "20130502" "commencement_date_of_contract_term" "20130427" ...
 $ contract_termination_date            : chr [1:156939] "20260630" "20280502" "contract_termination_date" NA ...
 $ actual_termination_date              : chr [1:156939] NA NA "actual_termination_date" NA ...
 $ extension_provision_description      : chr [1:156939] "None" "None" "extension_provision_description" "None" ...
 $ class_name                           : chr [1:156939] "UP" "UP" "class_name" "N/A" ...
 $ term_name                            : chr [1:156939] "LT" "LT" "term_name" "N/A" ...
 $ increment_name                       : chr [1:156939] "Y" "Y" "increment_name" "N/A" ...
 $ increment_peaking_name               : chr [1:156939] "FP" "FP" "increment_peaking_name" "N/A" ...
 $ product_type_name                    : chr [1:156939] "MB" "MB" "product_type_name" "MB" ...
 $ product_name                         : chr [1:156939] "ENERGY" "ENERGY" "product_name" "ENERGY" ...
 $ quantity                             : chr [1:156939] "498.96" "387" "quantity" NA ...
 $ units                                : chr [1:156939] "KW" "KW" "units" NA ...
 $ rate                                 : chr [1:156939] "0.3988" "0.2099" "rate" NA ...
 $ rate_minimum                         : chr [1:156939] NA NA "rate_minimum" NA ...
 $ rate_maximum                         : chr [1:156939] NA NA "rate_maximum" NA ...
 $ rate_description                     : chr [1:156939] NA NA "rate_description" "Market Based" ...
 $ rate_units                           : chr [1:156939] "$/KWH" "$/KWH" "rate_units" "$/MWH" ...
 $ point_of_receipt_balancing_authority : chr [1:156939] NA NA "point_of_receipt_balancing_authority" NA ...
 $ point_of_receipt_specific_location   : chr [1:156939] NA NA "point_of_receipt_specific_location" NA ...
 $ point_of_delivery_balancing_authority: chr [1:156939] "PGE" "PGE" "point_of_delivery_balancing_authority" NA ...
 $ point_of_delivery_specific_location  : chr [1:156939] "Interconnection of 3C Solar facility and PGE" "Interconnection of Newman facility and PGE" "point_of_delivery_specific_location" NA ...
 $ begin_date                           : chr [1:156939] NA NA "begin_date" NA ...
 $ end_date                             : chr [1:156939] NA NA "end_date" NA ...
 - attr(*, "spec")=
  .. cols(
  ..   contract_unique_id = col_character(),
  ..   seller_company_name = col_character(),
  ..   seller_history_name = col_character(),
  ..   customer_company_name = col_character(),
  ..   contract_affiliate = col_character(),
  ..   ferc_tariff_reference = col_character(),
  ..   contract_service_agreement_id = col_character(),
  ..   contract_execution_date = col_character(),
  ..   commencement_date_of_contract_term = col_character(),
  ..   contract_termination_date = col_character(),
  ..   actual_termination_date = col_character(),
  ..   extension_provision_description = col_character(),
  ..   class_name = col_character(),
  ..   term_name = col_character(),
  ..   increment_name = col_character(),
  ..   increment_peaking_name = col_character(),
  ..   product_type_name = col_character(),
  ..   product_name = col_character(),
  ..   quantity = col_character(),
  ..   units = col_character(),
  ..   rate = col_character(),
  ..   rate_minimum = col_character(),
  ..   rate_maximum = col_character(),
  ..   rate_description = col_character(),
  ..   rate_units = col_character(),
  ..   point_of_receipt_balancing_authority = col_character(),
  ..   point_of_receipt_specific_location = col_character(),
  ..   point_of_delivery_balancing_authority = col_character(),
  ..   point_of_delivery_specific_location = col_character(),
  ..   begin_date = col_character(),
  ..   end_date = col_character()
  .. )
 - attr(*, "problems")=<externalptr>
```

Comment: Very hard to tell as this question is missing some key elements which are needed to make it reproducible

Comment: @GuedesBF sorry, what elements should I provide to make it reproducible? I'll edit my code in if that helps.

Comment: Would be helpful to at the very least know the `str` of each table. Or a small subset of your data if it isn't private. For it to work as expected; both tables need to have the same col names, be in the same order, and be the same type.

Comment: @Jamie I've added in some information about the columns. I'm just confused to why it's having this issue now when it didn't before, even with those col_double() columns.

Comment: I'd suggest removing the double columns then if they don't exist in the first table.

Comment: @Jamie I removed the double columns, but the R Session still crashes. Is there anything else I can provide to you?

Comment: Hmm I'm not quite sure what's going on without being able to test the data. Can you share the output of `str(contracts201415)` and `str(contracts2015Q3)`? Or even a subset of the data from both tables? Maybe terminate your session and try again? Those files are not terribly big so it shouldn't be a memory issue.

Comment: @Jamie I have edited my output into the original post, hope it helps. Thank you.

Comment: You could try `bindlist <- lapply(list(contracts201415, contracts2015Q3), as.data.frame)` or with as.data.table. Reading `?data.table::rbindlist`, it doesn't mention supporting tibbles and spc_tbl_s

Comment: The second table has a class of `spec_tbl_df`. Which I'm leaning towards being the problem. Instead of using `read_csv` use `data.table::fread`. Or before you rbindlist. use `setDT(your_table)` to convert them to data.table first.

Comment: @Jamie I tried all of these and none of them worked, unfortunately. It might be an issue of the software I'm using? I really don't know what it is.

Comment: Is'n it caused by different number of columns in both dataframes? In first you have `customer_company_name` where in 2nd there is `seller_history_name` at the same position.